# Use LIKE in WHERE conditions in typeORM Typescript

Tags: postgresql, typescript, typeorm

I'm trying to query on a columns with SQL endswith in a Typescript app

```js
cont tracking_code = '65432'
repo.findValidOne({ where: { tracking_code }});
```

I want to change it so the `tracking_code` value ends with the tracking value that I have available on the code

The SQL equivalent would be

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM repo 
WHERE tracking_code LIKE '%65432' 
LIMIT 1;
```

I have tried using a raw query, but it's not what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `Like` find operator.

```js
import {Like} from 'typeorm';

cont tracking_code = '65432';
repo.findValidOne({ where: { tracking_code: Like(`%${tracking_code}`) }});
```